# Can a fish script distinguish between being sourced and executed?

Tags: fish

I have a fish script that exports some variables and launches a command at the end. I'd like to be able to source this file to bring these variables into the current shell session, but without executing the command at the end.

**The question**: Can I figure out whether the current file is being executed or sourced from within the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$_` environment variable to see
if your script is being "run" by the `source` command:

```
#!/bin/fish
if test "$_" = source
  echo got sourced
else
  echo was execed
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$_` environment variable to see if your script is being "run" by the `source` command. Note that the `source` command has a common alias ("`.`"), so you must check the `$_` environment variable against both `source` and `.`.

```
#!/bin/fish

if test "$_" != "source" -a "$_" != "."
    echo "not sourced"
else
    echo "was sourced"
end
```

A common use of this may be to give a warning to the user, iff the script was not sourced:

```
if test "$_" != "source" -a "$_" != "."
    echo "Run this script with \". ./activate.fish\" (aka: \"source ./activate.fish\")."
    exit 1
end
```

Replace `activate.fish` with the name of your script, of course.

Comment: How does this differ from the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/943730/167207) that was posted 8+ years ago?

Comment: It adds the `.` case (where `.` is an alias for `source`). It also adds a common use case of this check, which I wish was included in software like Python's venv activator (instead of just doing nothing silently and leaving you confused).

Comment: Okay. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what "source"ing a script does. Generally, executing a script will run it in a separate process. Sourcing it will execute it in the *current shell*. It will still execute each line.

Probably what you want to do is to filter out the last line. Try:

```
source (sed '$d' filename | psub)
```

The `psub` command is used to handle the output of some process as if it is a file. [Documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#psub)

Comment: That works, and is pretty interesting. What I was thinking about was something akin to the `if __name__ == __main__` trick from python, but this works just as well.